# DBMS for Payment Server Software

Tags: sql, rdbms, firebird

Can anybody tell me if usage of FireBird or PostgreSql can by used in a small e-mail payment or 1000 kiosk-terminal server's data management , which will mainly process very important financial data like balances, payment transactions ...  ?????
which open-source database server you will suggest in my case? I don't like MS SQL because its from Microsoft. oracle is tooooooooooooooooo costy for us... 
Can somebody professionally argue for PostgreSQL or for Firebird to be used in a pay-pal like payment server  ....

Comment: You want a professional argument while cutting down MS SQL (free in express edition) cause "It's from Microsoft"?

Comment: Express Edition is free but very limited. I don't like to have limitations....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justn an example :Firebird/RDB supported by the largest banking software maker in Russia

http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=4055

So i guess it can be used without issues for very important financial data like balances, payment transactions

Firebird it's easier to administrate than postgresql and it does have various linux ports (ubuntu,fedora,debian) if you need n secure os (selinux)

Answer (score 2):

Firebird is very good database : I use it every day and my customers are quite happy with it.

You can get more information on [Firebird News](http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=4055)

Here an older post about [Firebird and PostGresSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331946/what-do-you-guys-think-of-postgres-and-firebird-databases)

Answer (score 1):

see the url for comparison:

[comparison 1](http://www.amsoftwaredesign.com/pg_vs_fb)

[comparison 2](http://nikolajlindberg.blogspot.com/2008/03/firebird-vs-postgresql.html)

seems that postgresql has the upperhand based on the given comparison charts.